# getting data from NSMutableArray between the range 2 to 7 or 3 to end of the array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i Added 10 values in my NSMutableArray.....

Now i need to display in my table view from 5 to end of the array....

please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
[yourArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, [yourArray count] - 3)];
```

Comment: Can you help me out .... adding [yourArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(3, yourArray.count - 3)]];  to tableviewcell.....

Comment: @kiran, You need to assign the result of that to your data source, whatever that is.

Comment: i got 10 images in my NSMutableArray..... For TableView cell i did cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageList objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(3, imageList.count - 3)]]];

Comment: @kiran, You need to index into that array via the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, using the passed-in `indexPath`.